# Nginx reverse proxy and Apache serve on a subpath

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, proxy

I have a Node server running on background, and have an PHP Application running too, my question is how can I serve the Node server (using nginx) on the main path (/) while the PHP app (using Apache) on a subpath (for example /apacheserver)? Will Let's Encrypt work as intended if I only use it with NginX?

Thanks!

Comment: Refer to the "location" block in your conf file for the domain. You can specify location / is directed where ever you like and location /apacheserver to somewhere else. For example proxy_pass http://localhost:88 if Apache is bound to localhost and listening on port 80. For examples see http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html#conf_structure

Comment: @AdmiralNoisyBottom can't get it to work, I've made a location block /apacheserver which set some header proxies and then proxy_pass to the actual ip, but I get 404 Not Found visiting /apacheserver [Apache works great by itself, I visited https://127.0.0.1:8090 where it's listening and it works]

Comment: I used /apacheserver as an example and it needs to be the actual path. Do you have an actual path in your domain such as example.com/apachepath.  location /actual_path { proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090 }